# Rebol 3 - How do I submit a username and password through https?

Tags: https, rebol, rebol3

I'm trying to access the feed from my google account and I do not know how to send the user and password:

```
>> read https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
** Access error: protocol error: "Authentication not supported yet"

>> read https://user:pass@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom
** Access error: protocol error: "Authentication not supported yet"
```

How do you do this?

Comment: Currently the main build doesn't contain HTTPS. I'll respond based on the alternate 'Saphirion' build.

Comment: HTTPS is now also available in the [Ren/C](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c) build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, high-level support (using username:password@ in URLs) for authorization is not implemented in Rebol 3's HTTP scheme.

However, you can easily send the [HTTP `Authorization` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11.1) directly (for HTTP "basic" auth):

```
read [
    scheme: 'https
    host: "mail.google.com"
    path: "/mail/feed/atom"
    headers: [Authorization: join "Basic " enbase/base "user:pass" 64]
]
```